# Convert StreamReader to List of object

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I make a call like this :

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

The "line" content is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="...." xmlns:xsd="..." xmlns:xsi=".....">
   <soap:Body>
      <findResponse xmlns="....">
         <out>
            <MyType>
               <city>CityA</city>
               <firstName>AAA</firstName>
               <lastName>A</lastName>
            </MyType>
            <MyType>
               <city>CityB</city>
               <firstName>BBB</firstName>
               <lastName>B</lastName>
            </MyType>       
         </out>
      </findResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

public class MyType
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like return a List, with in this case 2 entries.

How can I do this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this instead:

```
var list = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream())
    .Descendants("MyType")
    .Select(elem => new MyType
    {
        FirstName = elem.Element("firstName").Value,
        LastName = elem.Element("lastName").Value,
        City = elem.Element("city").Value
    }).ToList();
```

As an aside, the `HttpWebResponse` implements `IDisposable` and should be placed inside a `using`. Therefore the entire command might look like this:

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    var list = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream())
        .Descendants("MyType")
        .Select(elem => new MyType
        {
            FirstName = elem.Element("firstName").Value,
            LastName = elem.Element("lastName").Value,
            City = elem.Element("city").Value
        }).ToList();
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** this could be a namespacing issue:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.your-namespace.com";
var list = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream())
    .Descendants(ns + "MyType")
    .Select(elem => new MyType
    {
        FirstName = elem.Element("firstName").Value,
        LastName = elem.Element("lastName").Value,
        City = elem.Element("city").Value
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Not a path to a file but StreamReader

Comment: Tried your second solution, Fiddler show than the webservice is called, the webservice result is correct but the list is empty.

Comment: @Kris-I, the `XName` (`MyType` in the example) is case-sensitive. Is everything spelled correctly? Did it throw some type of exception?

Comment: spelling ok, no exception just list empty

Comment: @Kris-I, and the response is **exactly** as you have shown in your question?

Comment: @Kris-I, try doing this, `XDocument.Load(...).Root ...`. So in other words, add the `Root` property in there **before** the `Descendants` call.

Comment: @Kris-I, I'll be honest; I'm a bit baffled. The response can't be what's in your question - or at least I don't see any way it can be. I've done that query numerous times before. It could of course be a namespacing issue. You could try adding the namespace before "MyType". If `http://www.adventure-works.com` were the namespace, the string to search would be `http://www.adventure-works.com/MyType`.

Comment: @Kris-I, please see my edit that includes a way of getting the right namespace without having to build some weird string.

Comment: Depending on the rules of the schema, you may need to add the namespace prefix to all of the child elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make a xml from your "line" where  out tag would be the root, then convert it into json, and then deserialize json into List:

```
var myListOfMyType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJson, typeof(MyType));
```

Comment: "Make a xml from your "line" where out tag would be the root" how ?

Comment: For example: myXmlDocument.LoadXml(line); var node = myXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//out") -- from this you can form your xml document/ You need such schema to fit your MyType class.